# Searching for the key using SIMD

Tags: c, simd, avx

I have the following struct, which stores keys and generic user-specified values:

```c
typedef struct {
        uint32_t  len;
        uint32_t  cap;
        int32_t  *keys;
        void     *vals;
} dict;
```

now I want to create a function which iterates over the `keys` and returns corresponding `value`.

The non-SIMD version:

```c
void*
dict_find(dict *d, int32_t k, size_t s) {
        size_t i;
        i = 0;

        while (i < d->len) {
                if (d->keys[i] == k) {
                        void *p;
                        p = (uint8_t*)d->vals + i * s;

                        return p;
                }

                ++i;
        }

        return NULL;
}
```

I tried to vectorize the snippet above and came up with this:

```c
void*
dict_find_simd(dict *d, int32_t k, size_t s) {
        __m256i ymm0;
        ymm0 = _mm256_broadcastd_epi32(*(__m128i*)&k);

        __m256i  ymm1;
        uint32_t i;
        int      m;
        uint8_t  b;

        i = 0;
        while (i < d->len) { // [d->len] is aligned in 32 byte box.
                ymm1 = _mm256_load_si256((__m256i*)(d->keys + i));
                ymm1 = _mm256_cmpeq_epi32(ymm1, ymm0);

                m = _mm256_movemask_epi8(ymm1);
                b = __builtin_ctz(m) >> 2;

                i += (8 +  b * d->len); // Artificially break the loop. 
                                        // Remember [i] stores the modified value.
        }

        if (i <= d->len)
                return NULL;

        i -= (8 + b * d->len); // Restore the modified value.
        i += b;

        void *p;
        p = (uint8_t*)d->vals + i * s;

        return p;
}
```

The function seems to be working correctly (didn't test it much)?

BUT, there are 2 problems:

- NOTE: I'm checking if the `i > d->len` then I return the pointer. The `i` can be overflowed and it will return `NULL` there. How can I solve this issue?
- You might noticed that I'm using a combination of `_mm256_movemask_epi8` and `__builtin_ctz` in order to get the index of found key. Is there a better way (maybe a single instruction that does get the position of non zero value) to do this (without AVX512)?

Comment: Why not simply `for(i=0; i<d-len; i+=8) { /* SIMD stuff */ if(b) break;}`?

Comment: I thought that branching is "no-go " with SIMD. Maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: Actually, you can also break with `if(m) break;` and do the calculation of `b` after the loop. Branching would be inefficient, if you would be processing a lot of very small arrays (which usually fit into a few registers). In that case there would be more efficient solutions. (There must be a duplicate for this question, but I don't want to look for it at the moment)

Comment: Artificially mangling with the loop-counter is generally a much bigger issue for performance, as it breaks many possibilities for loop-unrolling, preloading data, etc. It would be slightly better if you just introduced a new variable `break_next` and put that into the loop condition. But then you can also directly `break`.

Comment: @chtz didn't know that. Thank you for suggestion.

Comment: `__builtin_ctz(m)` is undefined behaviour if `m` is `0`.  Use `_tzcnt_u32(m)` is you want well-defined behaviour.  Most (all?) AVX2 CPUs have tzcnt.  In practice `__bultin_ctz(m)` will use tzcnt for most compilers and thus produce a well-defined result ayway.  But yeah, agreed with @chtz, that loop-counter update looks horrible, I think creating a dependency chain between the previous compare and the next iteration's load address, so you bottleneck on *latency* not throughput.

Comment: The normal way is to loop until you find a non-zero `m`, then ctz that, or hit the `len` limit.  Making the loop-branch do double duty is probably not better for branch prediction, and is vastly worse in other ways.  Also, coding style: at least in the scalar version, `for (size_t i = 0 ; i < d->len ; i++) { ... }`.  Separately declaring the loop counter and then assigning to it, and then using a while, is just obfuscation that makes the reader look for where you might need `i` *after* the loop.  And prefer declaring vars on the same line where you initialize.

Comment: I tested your suggestions... and they work. + the code looks much cleaner and simpler. Thank you all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm checking if the `i > d->len` then I return the pointer. The `i` can be overflowed and it will return `NULL` there. How can I solve this issue?

There are two ways you could handle the overflow (and a potential out-of-bound read caused by that).

1. Use vector implementation only up to `i` that is dividable by the vector size, in the number of elements. If the vector loop didn't find the element, complete the tail processing in scalar code. This solution might be good if the input data is obtained from elsewhere, and there is no easy way to optimize memory allocation and initialization past the end of the buffer.
2. Allow the read past the end of the buffer and make sure whatever is read there does not count as a valid (found) entry. Over-allocate the buffers to make sure you can always read a full vector worth of data. This is easy to do if you compare the resulting `i` against the number of elements in the container - if it is greater, then your algorithm "found" an element past the end and you should indicate that nothing is found. In some cases, this can come naturally from the nature of your data. For example, if you use a key value that will never be valid to fill past the end elements, or if your associated values can be used to the same effect (e.g. the past-the-end values are `NULL` pointers, which is also used to indicate the "not found" result).

> You might noticed that I'm using a combination of `_mm256_movemask_epi8` and `__builtin_ctz` in order to get the index of found key. Is there a better way (maybe a single instruction that does get the position of non zero value) to do this (without AVX512)?

I don't think there is a single instruction for this, but you could improve performance of this combination. Notice that you're comparing 32-bit values, meaning that `_mm256_movemask_epi8` produces a mask for 8 elements (4 equal bits each). You could improve data density if you compared 4 pairs of vectors, then packed the results so that each byte in a vector corresponds to a distinct comparison result, and then apply one `_mm256_movemask_epi8`.

```
ymm1 = _mm256_load_si256((__m256i*)(d->keys + i));
ymm2 = _mm256_load_si256((__m256i*)(d->keys + i) + 1);
ymm3 = _mm256_load_si256((__m256i*)(d->keys + i) + 2);
ymm4 = _mm256_load_si256((__m256i*)(d->keys + i) + 3);

ymm1 = _mm256_cmpeq_epi32(ymm1, ymm0);
ymm2 = _mm256_cmpeq_epi32(ymm2, ymm0);
ymm3 = _mm256_cmpeq_epi32(ymm3, ymm0);
ymm4 = _mm256_cmpeq_epi32(ymm4, ymm0);

ymm1 = _mm256_packs_epi32(ymm1, ymm2);
ymm3 = _mm256_packs_epi32(ymm3, ymm4);
ymm1 = _mm256_packs_epi16(ymm1, ymm3);
ymm1 = _mm256_permute4x64_epi64(ymm1, _MM_SHUFFLE(3, 1, 2, 0));
ymm1 = _mm256_shuffle_epi32(ymm1, _MM_SHUFFLE(3, 1, 2, 0));

m = _mm256_movemask_epi8(ymm1);
if (m)
{
    b = __builtin_ctz(m); // no shift needed here
    break;
}
```

(Note that `__builtin_ctz` result is undefined if `m` is zero, but you could mitigate this upon exiting the loop, if you check if `i` is within bounds. But, as shown above, I would rather test `m` before `__builtin_ctz` and use it to shortcut the `__builtin_ctz` and as a sign to break the loop.)

The problem with this is that packing is done per 128-bit lane, which means you would have to shuffle the bytes between lanes before you can use the result. This, and the packing itself, adds overhead that may somewhat negate the benefits from this optimization. If you use 128-bit vectors, you can save the shuffling, and it may improve overall performance. I did not benchmark the code, you will have to do the testing.

Another possible optimization to think of is to shortcut the packing/shuffling and `_mm256_movemask_epi8` if none of the comparisons are `true`. You could use `_mm256_testz_si256` to check if all the comparison result vectors are zero and break out of the loop only when they are not.

```
ymm1 = _mm256_load_si256((__m256i*)(d->keys + i));
ymm2 = _mm256_load_si256((__m256i*)(d->keys + i) + 1);
ymm3 = _mm256_load_si256((__m256i*)(d->keys + i) + 2);
ymm4 = _mm256_load_si256((__m256i*)(d->keys + i) + 3);

ymm1 = _mm256_cmpeq_epi32(ymm1, ymm0);
ymm2 = _mm256_cmpeq_epi32(ymm2, ymm0);
ymm3 = _mm256_cmpeq_epi32(ymm3, ymm0);
ymm4 = _mm256_cmpeq_epi32(ymm4, ymm0);

ymm5 = _mm256_or_si256(ymm1, ymm2);
ymm6 = _mm256_or_si256(ymm3, ymm4);
ymm5 = _mm256_or_si256(ymm5, ymm6);

if (!_mm256_testz_si256(ymm5, ymm5))
{
    ymm1 = _mm256_packs_epi32(ymm1, ymm2);
    ymm3 = _mm256_packs_epi32(ymm3, ymm4);
    ymm1 = _mm256_packs_epi16(ymm1, ymm3);
    ymm1 = _mm256_permute4x64_epi64(ymm1, _MM_SHUFFLE(3, 1, 2, 0));
    ymm1 = _mm256_shuffle_epi32(ymm1, _MM_SHUFFLE(3, 1, 2, 0));

    m = _mm256_movemask_epi8(ymm1);
    b = __builtin_ctz(m);

    break;
}
```

Here, 3 OR operations are faster than 3 packs + 2 shuffles, so you might save some cycles if your data is large enough (i.e. if on average you're not expected to find the result in the initial elements). If you find the elements predominantly among the first elements then this would show worse performance than the loop without `_mm256_testz_si256`.

---

Here is an updated version of the above code based on suggestions by **Peter Cordes** in the comments.

```
ymm1 = _mm256_load_si256((__m256i*)(d->keys + i));
ymm2 = _mm256_load_si256((__m256i*)(d->keys + i) + 1);
ymm3 = _mm256_load_si256((__m256i*)(d->keys + i) + 2);
ymm4 = _mm256_load_si256((__m256i*)(d->keys + i) + 3);

ymm1 = _mm256_cmpeq_epi32(ymm1, ymm0);
ymm2 = _mm256_cmpeq_epi32(ymm2, ymm0);
ymm3 = _mm256_cmpeq_epi32(ymm3, ymm0);
ymm4 = _mm256_cmpeq_epi32(ymm4, ymm0);

ymm1 = _mm256_packs_epi32(ymm1, ymm2);
ymm3 = _mm256_packs_epi32(ymm3, ymm4);
ymm5 = _mm256_or_si256(ymm1, ymm3);  // cheap result to branch on 

if (_mm256_movemask_epi8(ymm5) != 0)
{
    ymm1 = _mm256_packs_epi16(ymm1, ymm3);     // now put the bits in order
    ymm1 = _mm256_permutevar8x32_epi32(ymm1,   // or vpermq + vpshufd like before
        _mm256_setr_epi32(0, 4, 1, 5, 2, 6, 3, 7));

    m = _mm256_movemask_epi8(ymm1);
    b = __builtin_ctz(m);

    break;
}
```

The improvements were made having Skylake or similar microarchitecture in mind:

1. Move two of the packs above the condition. They will be able to execute efficiently given that only two `vpcmpeqd` per cycle can execute, which is enough to feed one `vpackssdw`. Two `vpcmpeqd` per cycle is achievable given that two loads per cycle can be issued. In other words, the two pack instructions competing for port 5 do not become the bottleneck.
2. `vpmovmskb` instruction is only one µop and has latency 2-3 cycles and `vptest` is two µops (3 cycles). The subsequent `test` will fuse with `jz`/`jnz`, so the condition on `_mm256_movemask_epi8` can execute slightly faster. Note that at this point `_mm256_movemask_epi8` is applied to a dummy vector `ymm5`, which is not used later to produce the correct result.
3. The two shuffles in my code version can be replaced with one with a vector constant. Here, I'm using `_mm256_setr_epi32` to initialize the constant, and decent compilers will convert it to an in-memory constant with no extra instructions. You may need to do this manually, if your compiler is not smart enough. Also, note that this constant is an additional memory access, which may get into play if your lookup tends to terminate early (i.e. if the code behind the condition significantly contributes to the total execution time of the algorithm). You could possibly mitigate this by loading the constant early, before entering the loop. The algorithm doesn't use many vector registers, so you must have plenty to spare to keep the constant loaded.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Just one thing: I don't understand how the first snippet will work? Shouldn't the offset be `+8, +16, ...` instead of `+1, +2`? If no how would that be more efficient?

And also for the `__builtin_ctz` Peter suggested to use  `_tzcnt_u32`. I think 
 I could go with that too (don't know how that works internally, maybe it does what you said).

Comment: @Hrant The `+1` etc. is added to a `__m256i*` pointer, so that works as intended. `_tzcnt_u32` is a valid option, but here, since you want to test the comparison result anyway, you don't need to apply it to a zero input, so `__builtin_ctz` works just fine.

Comment: I understand that `+1, +2...` is applied to pointer. But I don't get why we do that? Or how would that be more efficient. Do the latencies of those instructions not add up?  Not saying that the code is wrong. I'm just trying to understand it.

Comment: @Hrant Adding `+1` to a `__m256i*` pointer will increment it by 32 bytes (or 8 32-bit elements). So the 4 loads don't overlap and load 128 adjacent bytes worth of data. As for latencies, yes each load instruction has a latency, but modern CPUs can issue multiple loads in parallel (e.g. up to 2 loads per cycle for Skylake, if I'm not mistaken), so the latency can be hidden. Plus, the CPU may be able to speculatively execute multiple loop iterations in parallel, though in this case it will probably be memory bound anyway if the data is cold.

Comment: @Hrant You can see latencies and reciprocal throughput of various instructions in the [Intel Intrinsics Giode](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/). It may not be universally accurate, but it is very convenient to use. Also, see Agner Fog's invaluable [optimization manuals](https://www.agner.org/optimize/) for more performance data.

Comment: Aaaah, I'm stupid. I thought you're adding to the keys pointer and not casted pointer. Well hidden brackets (or I'm blind). I thought you intentionally wanted them to overlap each other.

Comment: I've updated the answer as it was missing one additional shuffle in the code samples.

Comment: @PeterCordes `_mm256_permute4x64_epi64` is `vpermq`, isn't it?

Comment: Also, vpmovmskb / test+jnz is only 2 uops after macro-fusion, but vptest / jnz is 2+1, so it's actually better to `if(movemask(v))` even on the "wrong" v than to use `if(_mm256_testz_si256(v,v))` when your v comes from a compare result (so the sign bit has the data you want.)

Comment: @AndreySemashev: Oh, brain fart, yes, `_mm256_permute4x64_epi64` is `vpermq`.  Hmm, right, after 2 steps of packing, you have things mixed up at dword granularity, not just qword. So you'd need `vpermd` to fix it in one step, and that would require a vector control constant.  (Which might be worth loading if you search often.)

Comment: @PeterCordes In order to perform `if(movemask(v))` (once) you would have to do the shuffling, which `vptest` avoids. Or you'd have to do multiple `if(movemask(v))` conditions per iteration. Also, I'm not sure I understand how you would move some packs outside the loop and keep one condition. I suppose, you could move them all out and only leave shuffes behind the condition. I'm not sure that would be faster since packs will execute serially (bottlebecked on p5) and 2 ORs can execute in parallel.

Comment: @AndreySemashev: No, `if(movemask(v))` works for detecting any non-zero element in a single vector (whether they're from OR or PACKSS), regardless of order.  When you find one, you then do the shuffling to put the bits in the right order, do a movemask on *that*, and tzcnt.  The if(movemask(early_out_test_vector) is just *just* part of a faster replacement for `_mm256_testz_si256`, not producing a result that's useful to use after the loop.

Comment: Re: 2x pack + 1x OR in the loop: `y1 = pack(cmp1, cmp2); y3 = pack(cmp3, cmp4)`.  Produce a temp as part of a loop condition: `if (movemask(or(y1,y3))` - inside that if, `y1 = pack(y1, y3)` and shuffle into order.  Re: port 5 pressure: remember that pack can't even run until its inputs are available, and at 2 loads per clock only 2 cmp results per clock can become ready.  That's enough to feed one pack.  OoO exec can overlap it.  loop body = 4 pcmp (macro-fused with loads), 2 pack, 1 POR, 1 pmovmsk, 1 test+jnz, 1 pointer increment, 1 cmp/jb = 11 fused-domain uops total, p5 isn't a bottleneck.

Comment: @PeterCordes I've updated the answer with the code reflecting your suggestions.